# Why do I recieve multiple warnings of "No running instance of xfce4-panel was found" when logging into Xubuntu?

Tags: login, xubuntu, startup, xfce-panel

I'm running Xubuntu 11.04, the bootup-time is quite fast but when I log in it takes close to a minute before the desktop is displayed, meanwhile I see no activity on the hard drive. When I finally have the desktop I see this notification repeated 10 times:

[image]

and then this one:

[image]

In `.config/autostart` I have these entries

```
$ ls
xfce4-settings-helper-autostart.desktop

xfce4-clipman-plugin-autostart.desktop  xfce-panel.desktop

$ cat xfce-panel.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=0.9.4
Type=Application
Name=xfce4-panel
Comment=
Exec=xfce4-panel
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

I need some assistance to locate the slow startup, which logs to look at etc.

And then this annoying message about xfce-panel. Where do I look for from where it is started.

Comment: Still wondering about this?  Incidentally, I don't think you ought to have a desktop file for the panel, not in autostart or anywhere else.  There should be no need to autostart it.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh Problem fixed (a long time ago :-) Was due to a faulty cache. Removed the .cache folder and restarted. Problem fixed.

Comment: That's great!  Do you mind putting an answer below and marking it solved?  It helps clean up the site, even if slightly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the questioner, the problem was fixed after removing the `.cache` folder in his home directory.

In some cases, as described [here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=32775#p32775), it might be necessary to:

- Log out of xfce
- Log in to a bare terminal (by pressing, e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and logging in)
- Delete `~/.cache` (just deleting the contents of `~/.cache/sessions` might suffice)
- Return to xfce (usually by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)
- Log in

Comment: And for me too.

Comment: This worked as long as I also unchecked the box that says "Save session for future logins" on the logout dialog box.